# How to read some data in python, saving that after manipulation

Tags: python

Suppose I read a file a csv file as a nested list in python. 
data in python looks like this:

```
my_data=[[1,4,6,2],
        [1,6,5,2],
        [1,2,1,6]]
```

and so on.

Suppose I have to do some cleaning with data in python( for several purpose). Data continues to look as a nested list in python. Now I want to take this data and export into a csv file so I can read them later without doing any cleaning process. Csv file would look like a classic excel file: for example first list

```
[1,4,6,2]
```

should be first row of the csv file and so on.

In which way should I proceed?

Comment: Have you looked at the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) reader and writer?

Comment: Please provide info on if either a) the data written to file will be nested or b) flattened. In case of a) we would need more details on how the nesting will be after the processing to suggest a good storage strategy in case of b) proceed eg as @CoryKramer suggests.

Comment: try to rephrase it. hope it's clear enough

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

_list = [[1, 4, 6, 2], [1, 6, 5, 2], [1, 2, 1, 6]]
filename = 'test.csv'

with open(filename, 'wb') as csvfile:
    a = csv.writer(csvfile)
    a.writerows(_list)

with open(filename, 'rb') as fn:
    read = csv.reader(fn, delimiter='\t')
    for row in read:
        print row[0]
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html